# Does air pressure change at the same rate on high elevation land as in the sky?

Tags: pressure, atmospheric-science, air

Is air pressure the same in a place like Denver, which is a mile (1.6 km) above sea level, as the same elevation above actual sea level? Same question for 2 miles high, as in any number of mountain peaks.

Thanks.

Comment: You mean that high above an actual ocean? Perhaps. Recall that the amount of moisture in the air impacts air pressure which is why you want a barometer for weather prediction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose a small cube of air at a height $h$ above the sea level. The force in the bottom is the must balance the pressure in the top plus the weight of the cube: $$F_b = F_t + w \implies p_b\Delta x\Delta y = p_t\Delta x \Delta y + \rho g(h) \Delta x \Delta y \Delta h \implies \Delta p = \rho g(h) \Delta h$$

It is possible to have a vertical pressure difference in a static situation due to gravity. But if we analyse the vertical faces of the cube, the result of any imbalance is acceleration. So, in a calm weather, the pressure is the same for a given altitude with respect to sea level, no matter how close is the soil below.

Answer (score 1):

Air pressure is the same at any hight it does not matter if there is a mountain this hight or just a balloon with a measuring instrument, thats why you need oxygen if you go on very high mountains and can get sick if you ascend too fast at this high (of cause the pressure also depends on the local high or low weather.)

Comment: Largely true. Temperature varies from place to place, and this has an effect. Moving air can make a difference, For example, air pressure is low in the center of a hurricane.